# Jquery 1.9.1 Permission Denied

Tags: javascript, jquery, permission-denied

could you help me on this ...

I've got a main page with an iframe inside (where the .asp pages will be load). This .asp pages have links that can jump from each other, always inside the iframe. They work fine.

At the main page, I've got a button that shows/hides the header and the menu divs, so the user is able to see only the iframe to gain space. I'm using jQuery to change the button image when the header and the menu divs are visible/hidden ... It works fine.

main page with button -> iframe -> page_a.asp -> <- page_b.asp

The weird is that the button stops working when I change from the page_a from page_b multiple times, giving the error:

permission denied on jquery-1.9.1.js: line 3896 and sometimes line 4392

a -> b -> a -> b -> button show/hide -------- stops working

a -> b -> button show/hide -> a -> b ... ---- works ok

I'm using IE9 ... In firefox or chrome it works fine!

If you need anything else that may help, I'm here :)

Thanks.

This is the jQuery code that i´m using:

```
$('#bt_menu').click(function(){
    $('#logo, #menu').slideToggle('fast', function(){
        if ($(this).is(":hidden") == true)
            //{$('#bt_menu p').text('Show MENU');}
            {$('#bt_menu').css('background-image','url(/images/down.png)');}
        else
            //{$('#bt_menu p').text('Hide MENU');}
            {$('#bt_menu').css('background-image','url(/images/up.png)');}
    });
});
```

If I simple apply it on a div, the error is the same. So the problem is not this code.

---

I figure that the error is related with the Iframe height ... I´ve got this function to fit the height of the contents:

```
$('iframe').load(function () {
    iframeHeight = $(this).contents().find('body').height();
    $(this).css('height', iframeHeight + 30);
});
```

If I comment this it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :
In IE Advanced settings, under browsing remove the tick on "Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer)" and run this in command prompt (with administrator rights):

```
regsvr32.exe "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\msdbg2.dll
```

If it doesn't work try migrating to jquery 2.0 that supports better IE.

I've also found this tutorial for you http://www.jquery4u.com/ie/jquery-1-9-1-overcomes-internet-explorer-678-javascript/ [HOW JQUERY 1.9.1 OVERCOMES IE Tutorial][1] that may help you to make some code adaptation for IE.

Else you can try a markup call :

```
<iframe id="myFrame" onload="myFunction();"></iframe>
```

and put your js code in myFunction()

Comment: Hi Imane, thanks. I follow your first suggestion and receive the error: "the module xxxx was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x800700005". After some research this means the following: "regsvr32 needs to be launched elevated; if UAC is enabled or regsvr32 is not elevated the register will fail with the above error code." This site will be used by other persons, so I will have to do it on every machine ... no good. I´ve also try to use jquery-2.0.0.min.js but the error is there, not on the same line ... IE suc**!

Comment: Same problem ... Just finish to test with the jQuery plugins and the button stops working ... the iframe su*** too :)

Comment: Do you have many jquery/javascript codes in your page? Ah and don't forget to clean your cache/cookies every time before testing (My little trick is using inPrivate mode).

Comment: the pages (a and b) just have asp ... and links to each other

Comment: I thought you were using php... developping for IE compatibility is the worst part for any web developper